# how to show next year date as a default date in Mobiscroll

Tags: jquery, mobile, datepicker, mobiscroll

I need to show some next year date as a default date in control. i.e when the control opens ; by default it should show next year date.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with this:

```
$(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    $('#i').scroller({
        preset: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        dateOrder: 'mmddyy'

    }).scroller('setDate',new Date(2013, now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0,0,0),true); 
});​
```

And a jsFiddle to it: http://jsfiddle.net/kovlex/jnTZc/